# I can't replace this pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I need your help on my new project
I hate regular expressions and its rules but i must use it this project.

want do this replace

```
var aString = '[bkz:sample key]';
```

I want get into key variable 'sample key' value from this aString

```
var key,clean;
key = 'sample key';
clean = cleanChars(key); 
// clean = sample_key


//my target
<a href="#/clean">key</a>
```

how can i do this?
thanks in advance

Comment: It's not too clear exactly what you want the regex to do.. Please add your expected input and output.

Comment: string is reserved... I change the variable name

Comment: It'll also help if you include some of your attempts to solve this (even if the code doesn't work).

Comment: I edit my question, Lix I want get 'sample key' value from main string, Thanks Hogan I'm trying your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function extractKey(str) {
    var match = (str || '').match(/^\[bkz:(.+)\]$/);
    return match? match[1] : '';
}


extractKey('[bkz:sample key]'); //sample key
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var aString = "[bkz:sample key]";

var regex = /^\[(.+)\:(.+)\]$/;

var matches = regex.exec(aString);

// "sample key" should now be in matches[2]
```

Comment: thank you my friend this worked but other answer more fulfill my needs.

Comment: fact is that you dont need to match "bkz" you can use / \ [.+:(.+) \ ] /

Comment: i must use "bkz" match becaues ı have several keys smiliar like "bkz".

Comment: that wasnt for you, that was for regex match, since you dont need to match "bkz" the answer didnt need to include it on match result, like $match[1] and $match[2] / \ [ bkz:(.+) \ ] /